# Can it possible to parse LocalDate by DateTimeFormatter only?

Tags: date, java-8

Today I'm parsing *epoch* time to a *String*, like this:

```
private String convertEpochTime(Long timeInEpoch) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
            .format(new java.util.Date (timeInEpoch * 1000));
}
```

I want to use **Java 8** new *LocalDate* API, instead of using a String, but didn't find a way of doing it.

I wish I just could do:

```
private LocalDate convertEpochTime(Long timeInEpoch) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").format(new java.util.Date (timeInEpoch * 1000));
    return LocalDate.parse(dateTimeFormatter);
}
```

Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Instant.ofEpochSecond`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) and then convert the instant to a `LocalDate`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timeInEpoch);
LocalDate localDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

or if you want to have time as well, convert to a `LocalDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```

Instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()` you may need to use a different zone depending on your needs.

So there is no need to use a string as intermediary.